# How to configure/swap devicons in nvim

Tags: icons, neovim

[Pic of Nertree boxs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWsFv.png)

I am using VimPlug. Installed NERDTREE, Installed NERDFONT Arimo, Installed nvimtree/nvim-web-devicons

New to NVIM, I think it is all running, but not sure how to replace the box next to folder in NERDTREE with a different icon.

One thing I am running Ubuntu terminal on WSL, and haven't figure out how to change my terminal font.